# Is there a way to display Text in small caps in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm searching for a way to display a Google Font in small caps.

I'm using the [google_fonts](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts) package.

Comment: Do you want to apply it at the application level or to a specific text?

Comment: @faroukosama Just to a specific text :)

Comment: just add   .toLowerCase() after specific  text

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `FontFeature` property inside a `TextStyle` like this:

```
import "dart:ui";

Text('This is a Google Font',
      style: GoogleFonts.lato(
        textStyle: TextStyle(fontFeatures:[FontFeature.enable('smcp')], color: Colors.blue, letterSpacing: .5), 
        //smcp as in small caps
      ),
    ),
```